# Django Add Edit Form - Field has no attribute assigned to it?

Tags: python, django

Im trying to combine an add and edit form into one and am receiving an error The 'site_image' attribute has no file associated with it.

I could edit files but could not add files, but now when I load the site files page I am receiving the below error, I havent changed the model so am unsure as to why im receiving this error.

the list of files shouldn't really care if site_image is there or not as its set to blank and null?

my file model:

```
class SiteFiles(models.Model):
    site_data = models.ForeignKey(SiteData, verbose_name="Site", on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    site_image = models.ImageField(upload_to='site_files/', blank=True, null=True)
    site_image_thumbnail = ImageSpecField(source='site_image',
                                            processors=[ResizeToFill(200, 150)],
                                            format='JPEG',
                                            options={'quality': 60})
    site_file = models.FileField(blank=True, upload_to=site_files_path, \
                validators=[validate_file_extension])
    file_name = models.CharField(max_length=200, verbose_name="File Name")
    file_type = models.CharField(max_length=100, verbose_name='File Type', \
                choices=settings.FILE_TYPE)
    class Meta:
        verbose_name = "Site Files"
        verbose_name_plural = "Site Files"

    def __str__(self):
        return '%s | %s | %s ' % (self.site_data.location, self.site_data.location, self.file_name)
```

my forms.py

```
class FileForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = SiteFiles
        fields = ['site_image', 'site_file', 'file_name','file_type']

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(FileForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.helper = FormHelper(self)
        self.helper.form_id = 'file_form'
        self.helper.form_method = 'POST'
        self.helper.add_input(Submit('submit', 'Save', css_class='btn-primary'))
        self.helper.layout = Layout(
            Div(    
                Div(
                    Div(
                        Div(HTML('<i class="fa fa-camera-retro fa-fw"></i> Add File or Photo'), css_class='panel-heading'),
                        Div(
                            Field('site_image', placeholder='Image'),
                            Field('site_file', placeholder='File'),
                            Field('file_name', placeholder='Display Name'),
                            Div('file_type', title="File Type"),
                            css_class='panel-body'
                        ),
                    css_class='panel panel-default',
                    ),
                css_class='col-lg-3'
                ),
            css_class='row'
            ),
        )
```

my views.py

```
@login_required
@user_passes_test(lambda u: u.has_perm('sites.add_sitefile'))  
def add_edit_file(request, site_id, item_id=None):
    from sites.forms import FileForm
    from sites.models import SiteFiles
    site_data = get_object_or_404(SiteData, pk=site_id) 
    # set edit values
    if item_id:
        item_data = get_object_or_404(SiteFiles, pk=item_id) 
        form_type = 'Edit'
        form = FileForm(instance=item_data)
    else:
        # set add values
        form = FileForm()
        form_type = 'Add'
        item_data = SiteFiles()
    # set posting
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = FileForm(request.POST,instance=item_data)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.instance.site_data = site_data
            form.save()
            return redirect('sites:site_detail_files', site_id)

    return render(request, 'sites/add_edit_file.html', {
        'add_edit_file_form': form,  
        'SiteName' : site_data.location,
        'SiteID' : site_id, 
        'ItemID' : item_id,         
        'FormType' : form_type
    })
```

Error:

```
Traceback:

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in _resolve_lookup
  882.                     current = current[bit]

During handling of the above exception ('ImageFieldFile' object is not subscriptable), another exception occurred:

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py" in inner
  41.             response = get_response(request)

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in _legacy_get_response
  249.             response = self._get_response(request)

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in _get_response
  187.                 response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in _get_response
  185.                 response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/decorators.py" in _wrapped_view
  23.                 return view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "/itapp/itapp/sites/views.py" in site_detail_files
  311.         'active_files' : 'class="active"',

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/shortcuts.py" in render
  30.     content = loader.render_to_string(template_name, context, request, using=using)

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/loader.py" in render_to_string
  68.     return template.render(context, request)

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/backends/django.py" in render
  66.             return self.template.render(context)

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in render
  207.                     return self._render(context)

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/test/utils.py" in instrumented_test_render
  107.     return self.nodelist.render(context)

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in render
  990.                 bit = node.render_annotated(context)

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in render_annotated
  957.             return self.render(context)

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/loader_tags.py" in render
  177.             return compiled_parent._render(context)

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/test/utils.py" in instrumented_test_render
  107.     return self.nodelist.render(context)

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in render
  990.                 bit = node.render_annotated(context)

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in render_annotated
  957.             return self.render(context)

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/loader_tags.py" in render
  177.             return compiled_parent._render(context)

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/test/utils.py" in instrumented_test_render
  107.     return self.nodelist.render(context)

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in render
  990.                 bit = node.render_annotated(context)

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in render_annotated
  957.             return self.render(context)

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/loader_tags.py" in render
  72.                 result = block.nodelist.render(context)

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in render
  990.                 bit = node.render_annotated(context)

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in render_annotated
  957.             return self.render(context)

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/defaulttags.py" in render
  216.                     nodelist.append(node.render_annotated(context))

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in render_annotated
  957.             return self.render(context)

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/library.py" in render
  202.         resolved_args, resolved_kwargs = self.get_resolved_arguments(context)

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/library.py" in get_resolved_arguments
  188.         resolved_args = [var.resolve(context) for var in self.args]

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/library.py" in <listcomp>
  188.         resolved_args = [var.resolve(context) for var in self.args]

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in resolve
  708.                 obj = self.var.resolve(context)

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in resolve
  849.             value = self._resolve_lookup(context)

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in _resolve_lookup
  890.                         current = getattr(current, bit)

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/files.py" in url
  69.         self._require_file()

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/files.py" in _require_file
  46.             raise ValueError("The '%s' attribute has no file associated with it." % self.field.name)

Exception Type: ValueError at /sites/site/files/7
Exception Value: The 'site_image' attribute has no file associated with it.
```

EDIT:

site_details_files:

```
@login_required        
def site_detail_files(request, site_id):
    files = SiteFiles.objects.filter(site_data__id=site_id)
    try:
        site = files[0].site_data    
    except:
        site = get_object_or_404(SiteData, pk=site_id)  

    return render(request, 'sites/site_detail_files.html', {
        'Files': files,
        'SiteName' : site.location,
        'SiteID' : site.id,
        'PageType' : 'files',
        'active_files' : 'class="active"',
    })
```

template:

```
{% block content %}
<div class="col-lg-9">
    <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading">
            <i class="fa fa-camera fa-fw"></i> Photos
        </div>
        <div class="panel-body">
            {% get_file_type Files 'Cabinet Photo' as photos %} 
            {% for file in photos %}
                <div class="img-item">
                    <div class="img">
                        <a class="image-float-left" id="" href="{% signed_url file.site_image.url %}" target="_blank">
                            <img src="{% signed_url file.site_image_thumbnail.url %}" alt="" />
                        </a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="img-text">
                        {{ file.file_name }}
                        <div class="img-edit" >
                            <a href="{% url 'sites:edit_file' SiteID file.id %}" class="edit-icon">
                                <i class="fa fa-edit"></i>
                            </a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <!-- /.img-item-->
            {% endfor %}
        </div>
        <!-- /.panel-body-->
    </div>
    <!-- /.panel-->
</div>
<!-- /.col-lg-9 -->
<div class="col-lg-3">
    <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading">
            <i class="fa fa-file-text-o fa-fw"></i> Files
        </div>
        <div class="panel-body">
                {% exclude_file_type Files 'Cabinet Photo' as site_files %} 
                {% for file in site_files %}
                <ul>
                {% if file.file_type != "Cabinet Photo" %}          
                    {% if file.site_file %}
                    <li>
                        <a href="{% url 'sites:edit_file' SiteID file.id %}" class="edit-icon">
                                <i class="fa fa-edit fa-1x"></i>
                        </a>
                        <a href="{% signed_url file.site_file.url %}" target="_blank">{{ file.file_name }}</a>
                    </li>
                    {% endif %}
                    {% if file.site_image %}
                    <li>
                        <a href="{{% url 'sites:edit_file' SiteID file.id %}" class="edit-icon">
                                <i class="fa fa-edit"></i>
                        </a>
                        <a href="{% signed_url file.site_image.url %}" target="_blank">{{ file.file_name }}</a>
                    </li>
                    {% endif %}
                {% endif %}
                </ul>
            {% endfor %}
        </div>
        <!-- /.panel-body-->
    </div>
    <!-- /.panel-->
</div>
<!-- /.col-lg-9 -->
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: the fix that you posted and removed has resolved the error but files are not uploaded anymore

Comment: I also deleted all the test files from the DB that I uploaded, I think those had issues

Comment: "but files are not uploaded anymore" -- that's not enough information to debug. Why are the files not uploaded anymore? If `form.is_valid()` is now `False`, then check `form.errors`.

Comment: this issue was fixed with the enctype="multipart/form-data" so two issues fixed, only one left is why site_details_files errors out if I have removed a site_image from a record

Comment: I think that's because you are trying to access `file.site_image.url` in the template after you removed `site_image`.

Comment: think you're right, I added {% for file in photos %}
            {% if file.site_image %} and now the page loads again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass `request.FILES` to the form when uploading files.

```
form = FileForm(request.POST, request.FILES, instance=item_data)
```

Make sure that you set `enctype="multipart/form-data"` in the template as well.

See the docs on [file uploads](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/http/file-uploads/) for more info.

However, these changes won't solve your error, since it is coming from a different view `site_detail_files`. It looks as if you are using `file.site_image.url` in the template without checking `file.site_image` first. You should add an extra if block:

```
{% for file in photos %}
    ...
    {% if file.site_image %}
        ...
        <a class="image-float-left" id="" href="{% signed_url file.site_image.url %}" target="_blank">
        ...
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: ok the issue is when I remove a site image from a record it seems, site_details_files added